# Is it possible to deploy a standalone ASP.NET application to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net

Is it possible to deploy a standalone ASP.NET application to SharePoint 2010, as you could in SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Thanks. Is that via the _layouts directory as in SP 2007?

Comment: Sure, I highly recommend that you create a SharePoint solution and deploy your application via it (even though you will not have any SharePoint code in your application)